# `react-apollo` `MockedProvider` requires timeout?

Tags: javascript, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm using `jest` with react-apollo's `MockedProvider` and I'm having trouble because the `MockedProvider` seems to be behaving asynchronously.

Given the following simple component:

`const Component = () => <Query query={query}>(({loading, data }) => if(loading) return 'loading' else if (data) return 'data' else return 'nothing'</Query>`

This test:

```
it('', done => {
    const renderer = TestRenderer.create(
      <MockedProvider mocks={myMock} >
        <Component/>
      </MockedProvider>
    )

  expect(renderer.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot()
```

shows a snapshot of: `loading`

but if I add a simple timeout of 1 ms:

```
  it('', done => {
    const renderer = TestRenderer.create(
      <MockedProvider mocks={myMock} >
        <Component/>
      </MockedProvider>
    )

    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(renderer.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot()
      done()
    }, 1);
```

I get a snapshot of: `data`

Is there a more elegant way to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use waait lib like shown at this [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/guides/testing-react-components.html#Testing-final-state)

```
it('',async () => {
    const renderer = TestRenderer.create(
      <MockedProvider mocks={myMock} >
        <Component/>
      </MockedProvider>
    )
    await wait(0);
    expect(renderer.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious if other's have ideas.

Right now having to do something like this:

```
export const AsyncTestRenderer = async elements => {
  /** Render, then allow the event loop to be flushed before returning */
  const renderer = TestRenderer.create(elements)

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(renderer), 1)
  })
}
```

and using it in a test:

```
const renderer  = await AsyncTestRenderer(
  <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} >
    <MyComponent/>
  </MockedProvider>
)

expect(renderer.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot() // renders data from mock Query
```