# Mocking data returned by useQuery using MockedProvider

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, apollo-client, react-testing-library

I have a simple component. All it does is fetch data using useQuery and pass it to another component. The component works fine, but I am unable to test it without adding hacks as described here:

[Testing Final Stage](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/#testing-final-state)

I have had a look at [MockedProvider requires timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50224714/react-apollo-mockedprovider-requires-timeout), and this was asked 2.5 years back. Is there any other way available? I can't believe the library team advocates putting wait/setTimeout in units!

Component:

```
export const PROFILE_QUERY = gql`
  query {
    profile {
      roles
    }
  }
`;

export const Connected = () => {
  const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(PROFILE_QUERY);
  const setCurrentProfile = (role: string) => {
    cachedSettings(getSettings(role));
  };
  const roles = data?.profile?.roles;
  return <Profile {...{ roles, loading, error, setCurrentProfile }} />;
};
```

Test Case:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router';
import Profile from '../Profile';
import ConnectedProfile from '..';
import { MockedProvider, MockedResponse } from '@apollo/client/testing';
import { PROFILE_QUERY } from '../Profile.connected';

jest.mock('../Profile', () => {
  return jest.fn(() => null);
});

describe('Connected <Profile />', () => {
  const renderComponent = (roles: string[] | undefined) => {
    const mock: MockedResponse = {
      request: {
        query: PROFILE_QUERY
      },
      result: {
        data: {
          profile: {
            roles
          }
        }
      }
    };

    return render(
        <MockedProvider mocks={[mock]} addTypename={false}>
          <MemoryRouter>
            <ConnectedProfile />
          </MemoryRouter>
        </MockedProvider>
    );
  };

  it('multiple roles must have been passed', async () => {
    renderComponent(['foo', 'bar']);
    **//DOCUMENTATION  says do following? - will have to wrap rendering in act as well
    //await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));**
    const args = (Profile as jest.Mock).mock.calls[0][0];
    expect(args.roles).toEqual(['agent', 'administrator']);
  });

  it('no roles passed', async () => {
    renderComponent(undefined);
    //DOCUMENTATION says do following?
    //await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
    const args = (Profile as jest.Mock).mock.calls[0][0];
    expect(args.roles).toEqual(undefined);
  });

  afterEach(() => (Profile as jest.Mock).mockClear());
});
```

Comment: A delay is needed if MockedProvider works like that. Testing Library encourages the use of waitFor to not rely on the implementation.

Comment: WaitFor is a good strategy but in my case I don't really want to test for an element which is rendered by the child component, all I want to test is the props which are being passed.

Comment: waitFor isn't restricted to elements, it's for any asynchronous assertions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `MockedProvider` is asynchronous and contains one-tick delay, a requirement to delay at least for the same amount of time is reasonable. This is a common issue for asynchronous tests and this is what popular `flush-promises` utility does.

React Testing Library is focused on blackbox testing and encourages the use of `waitFor` helper to not rely on the implementation. It may result in accumulated test time due to polling intervals:

```
renderComponent(undefined);
await waitFor(() => {
  expect(Profile).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  expect(Profile).toBeCalledWith(expect.objectContaining({ roles: undefined }));
});
```

Since this `MockedProvider` behaviour is known and documented, it can be safely implemented in `renderComponent` helper itself:

```
const renderComponent = async (roles: string[] | undefined) => {
    ...
    const result = render(
        <MockedProvider mocks={[mock]} addTypename={false}>...</MockedProvider>
    );
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve));
    return result;
};

...
await renderComponent(undefined);
expect(Profile).toBeCalledTimes(1);
expect(Profile).toBeCalledWith(expect.objectContaining({ roles: undefined }));
```